# How to set fileformat=unix for all files opend in vim?

Tags: vim

I want change fileformat of all the files.

So I open them use `vim *`.

Then I want to know if there is any simple way to do this, rather than typing `:set fileformat=unix` and `:w`for each file one by one.

Comment: maybe you can use dos2unix for ALL your file in shell first

Comment: @HowChen: thank you for providing this command. But I also want to do how to do same operation to all opened files in vim.

Comment: Why do you want to do it via vim?  Why is that better than doing it in the shell with `dos2unix`?

Comment: @AndyLester: I have done that with dos2unix. And I think I may need to do same operation to many files in vim in other cases.

Comment: @pktangyue: You should not need to convert line endings in vim if you have already done it with `dos2unix`.  Why do you think you need to do it in vim?

Comment: @pktangyue: or you write `set fileformat=unix` in your vimrc file? i believe in some reasons, files you `cp` from windows will have `^M` in them. If this the problem, use `:%s/^M//g` for all file is ok as well. @AndyLester: what's u opinion?

Comment: @AndyLester: I have solved this with dos2unix. And now what I'm care for is how I can do some change to many files, such as :$s/^m//g for every files in vim. And I think this example I give is really poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need  `bufdo`?

```
 :help bufdo
 bufdo[!] {cmd}     Execute {cmd} in each buffer in the buffer list.
 It works like doing this: 
                :bfirst
                :{cmd}
                :bnext
                :{cmd}
                etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. And I find other similar commands, like :windo :tabo :argdo.

Comment: An example would have been great

Comment: You can do it like this: `:bufdo set ff=dos | w`

Answer (score 12):

`argdo` is what you want, not `bufdo`, since you want to do it on every argument and you don't (necessarily) want to open every file first.

```
:argdo set ff=unix | update
```

should do the trick.

Comment: More info at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do this using vim record and play feature. Follow these steps

```
1. Open all files using vim *
2. Press "qq" to start recording
3. :set ff=unix
4. :wn
5. Press again "q" to stop recording
6. Execute like "100@q"
```

Here 100 is the approximate number of files, but don't worry if you gave more number also. It'll stop when it finishes all buffer saying "E165: Cannot go beyond last file". You can get the number of file is by doing "ls | wc -l" before you open.

Comment: Or simply `:bufdo set ff=dos | w`

Comment: @sarath This is an old thread, but you let me know this method to apply something to all buffers, and this has saved me literally one (or may two) days in my precious life, and ensuring error free. The Good News should be spread for the whole human race.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)